# VSCode for Mac is overwriting textmate scopes in favor of semantic token types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, textmate

I don't fully understand textmate scopes vs semantic token type, but my vs code editor on my mac 
is overridding/crossing out:

```
foreground  support.class { "foreground": "#66D9EF", "fontStyle": "italic" }
```

in favor of:

```
foreground  variable.other.readwrite
variable { "foreground": "#F8F8F2", "fontStyle": "" }
```

for the following textmate scopes:

```
support.class.builtin.ts
meta.object.member.ts
meta.objectliteral.ts
meta.object.member.ts
meta.objectliteral.ts
new.expr.ts
meta.var.expr.ts
source.ts

support.class.builtin.ts
meta.object.member.ts
meta.objectliteral.ts
meta.object.member.ts
meta.objectliteral.ts
new.expr.ts
meta.var.expr.ts
source.ts

support.class.builtin.ts
meta.function-call.ts
meta.object.member.ts
meta.objectliteral.ts
meta.object.member.ts
meta.objectliteral.ts
new.expr.ts
meta.var.expr.ts
source.ts
```

Also for "Number" in `Number.parseInt()` it seems to completely ignore it. The scope inspector shows:

```
foreground  support.class { "foreground": "#66D9EF", "fontStyle": "italic" }
```

although the text is white (not light blue) and not italic either.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling vs code but that hasn't helped.

Also, I notice when I quit vscode (on mac) then open it again, for a split second the override isn't in effect and the style on the above is light blue and italicized, but then it switched back to white regular text.

Please let me know what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Try disabling this setting: `Editor: Semantic Highlighting` a recent change to vscode.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!!

Comment: I know comments shouldn't be used to thank someone or complain. But I have just been so miserable because of this problem for weeks. Thank you so much @Mark